# StringTokenizer array

Tags: java, arrays, stringtokenizer, parseint

Java.
So I want to input an array of integers and then print out the max value using StringTokenizer. I know how to do this using integers, but when I try to do it with an array the String to int command (Integer.parseInt) fails me - cannot convert from int to int[].

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String strTmp;
        StringTokenizer strTok;
        while ((strTmp = in.readLine()) != null && strTmp.length() != 0) {
            strTok = new StringTokenizer(strTmp);

        int[] c;

        c = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());

        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] > max) {
                max = c[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
}
```

How do I go about solving this or are there other commands I should be using?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` returns an integer, not an array of integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about whether you actually want an array or not. You're parsing a *single value*, but trying to assign that `int` to `c` which is an array variable. You don't really *need* one, as you only need to remember the current maximum, and the value you've just parsed:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());
    if (value > max) {
        max = value;
    }
}
```

If you *really* want an array, then you'll need to know how many tokens there are before you parse them, which is tricky.

Another alternative would be to create a `List<Integer>`:

```
// First parse everything...
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    values.add(Integer.parse(strTok.nextToken());
}

// Then you can find the maximum value in the list
```

Personally I prefer the first approach, if you only need to find the maximum value.

Comment: the second approach is beyond me, have no knowledge of those commands, while the first approach works! but I don't exactly know what you did there

Comment: @user2974951: Well, follow it through line by line - which exact bit do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] c;

 c = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());
```

You are trying to assign a single Integer object to an array of `int`.

Rather, use `int[index] = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());`

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(String)` returns an integer, not an `Integer array`. You have to store the return value Integer in an int variable like

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(String);
```

You have to iterate the integer array and set it's index value to the returned integer value

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
           c[i] = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());
            if (c[i] > max) {
                max = c[i];
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!